# Sony Xperia Play Controls Mapping

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, sony

i am developing a game for Sony xperia play.

Can any one help me out to map controls button for the device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
You can go here to get the more info on keycodes http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2011/02/13/xperia-play-game-keys/